# Format cell from general to text

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I'm trying to write a little script that opens Excel, formats cell `B1` to text and saves the file, but I cant get "format to text" to work. Does someone know what I'm missing here?

It's this line that isn't working: `ExcelObj.Cells("B").Value = "@"`

```
Set ExcelObj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
ExcelObj.DisplayAlerts = False
ExcelObj.Visible  = true    ' or false
ExcelObj.Workbooks.Open "C:\Supplier\DK\ExternalPrices\Mapforcecode\Computercity\excelmapping\ExternalPrices.xlsx"
ExcelObj.Cells("B").Value = "@"
ExcelObj.Workbooks(1).SaveAs "\\file-srv1\Scalepoint\Supplier\Catalog\Data\DK\Computercity\Current\ExternalPrices.xlsx", 51
ExcelObj.Quit
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ExcelObj.ActiveSheet.Range("B1").NumberFormat = "@"
```

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/ff196273.aspx). The `Cells` property expects row and column number:

```
ExcelObj.Cells(1, 2).NumberFormat = "@"
```

If you want to use `"B1"` notation you must use the [`Range`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/ff836512.aspx) property:

```
Set wb = ExcelObj.Workbooks.Open "C:\Supplier\...\ExternalPrices.xlsx"    
wb.Sheets(1).Range("B1").NumberFormat = "@"
wb.SaveAs "\\file-srv1\Scalepoint\...\ExternalPrices.xlsx", 51
wb.Close
```

Note, however, that `Range` is relative to the active cell, so depending on whether or not your active cells is `A1` you may refer to different cells. The indexing of `Cells` is absolute.

Comment: thank you for the lesson, i will start to look in the documentation, thanks :)

Comment: This does not change the formatting of the cell. It only changes the value of it. His `Cells/Range` issue is part of the problem. Using `Value` instead of `NumberFormat` is the rest.